# How to create a category menu like the one here

Tags: menu

Hi Guys still learning every day how to use Magento. My site is coming along nicely http://www.cellar2door.com but wanted some advice on something I saw on another site.

When I look at this site http://www.reedandbarton.com/serveware/barware-pitchers-accessories and that category I see on the left hand side of the page a menu that you can check boxes to further refine the products you are looking at.

Is this something off the shelf or is it something that has been built specially? If it is off the shelf what would I google to find similar products?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into setting up [layered navigation for your categories](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-does-layered-navigation-work). It looks like the site you referenced is using layered navigation with some styling changes, or a 3rd party extension, to accomplish this.

edit: Also, for your attributes that you want to make filter products, go to your Magento Admin -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes. Click on the attribute to edit, and on the properties tab, scroll down to "Frontend Properties" and make sure that the value for "Use In Layered Navigation" is set to "Yes".  This will require that the attribute is of the input type Dropdown, Multiple Select, or Price.

Comment: It looks as good answer. However, article isn't clear about way to set category as anchor and Magento uses unfortunate naming there. I would like to add that you can do this by setting "Is Anchor" to "Yes" in Display Settings tab in category edit form.